# Z-order and owned windows

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, z-order

I'm trying to understand the behavior of owned windows

I have window A which is an owner (not parent) of Window B
I have another window C which is an owner (not parent) of window D

Say the z-order of windows is originally  A, B, C, D

Then window B is activated by the user clicking on it.

Sometimes the Z order becomes like this. C, D, A, B
and sometimes it becomes A, C, D, B??

None of the windows have the TopMost property set.  I'm using .NET 4.0.  I know that an owned window is always above its owner in the z-order, which is true in this case.  However, I would always like to get the order C,D,A,B when the user activate B. Is the only way to do this is to use SetWindowPos?

Comment: Simply bring the owner window into the foreground.  The owned window comes along for the ride.

Comment: The user is activating B by clicking on it...for your suggestion, do you mean listening for that event and then bringing window A up?  I thought of that but was hoping for a nicer solution.

Comment: Nicer solutions are apps that don't create more than one main window.  Just look at other apps you have on your machine, like VS.

Comment: I don't think you get a notification of any kind when the Z order changes, so that's a non-starter.

Comment: Can't change the app unfortunately....For notification, I meant to listen for the event when window B is activated, at which point I can try to change the z-order of window A

Comment: Are your owner and owned windows in multiple processes/threads? owner/owned (and parent/child) windows have their input queues attached, and having attached input queues is a [really](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/10/479124.aspx) [bad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/21/10131989.aspx) [idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/07/10424279.aspx).